# Can't find spring class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - which jar is it in?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Which jar contains the following Spring class:

```
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`spring-security-config-<VERSION>.jar`

This should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also note that it isn't included until version 3.2+ So you will want to ensure your version is 3.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: most recent version should be here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config

Answer (score 10):

### Updated Answer for 2022:

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** has been deprecated in Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 to encourage security configuration in components. The [official blog](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) explains how to achieve the same functionality through other alternatives such as SecurityFilterChain.

Answer (score 1):

It is in Spring-Security-Config jar

For Gradle add the following line in dependencies -

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.3.0.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous one is old, use this one

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue even after adding the spring-security-config. I fixed the problem adding the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

To avoid also getting the "deprecated" warning you can add:

```
<properties>
    <spring-security.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <spring.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the project parent version in pom.xml because WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is a deprecated (from spring boot 2.7.x)
so try to modify :

parent
groupId     org.springframework.boot      /groupId
artifactId  spring-boot-starter-parent    /artifactId
version     2.7.5.RELEASE                     /version

/parent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

WebSecuritiyconfigurerAdapter is deprecated pls follow following URL
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: This answer does not provide any additional information than [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75038709/1030169)

Comment: Please don't add answers with the same solution as other ones. Edit this answer with new content or remove it